# Class not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below code i have used codeigniter code i have found a error class not found.
Class 'Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\todo1\application\controllers\login.php on line 3

```
<?php

class Login extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CI_Controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
```

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter ( I think version 2.x.x ) you should use the following instead:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }
```